# Rails log is not logging anything on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have setup my application on ubuntu server but it is not logging logs in production.log file.

Here is my production.rb file contents.

```
# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

I made changes below but still file is empty on server.

```
# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('log/production.log')
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.log_level = :debug
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

Is this related to file permission on production server? Or what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` env var is present? Also, can you see logs in the standard output? Or standard output is empty as well?

Comment: I set it to true on production server. But how I can check it? Standard output be like?

Comment: Here is more info: root@xxxxxx:/home/xxxxx# sudo tail -f log/production.log
tail: cannot open 'log/production.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining

Comment: Are you *sure* it's been set correctly? Not set after the the server has already started?

Comment: I think its set after the server has already started but I am not sure sorry.

Comment: Permissions on log folder: `drwxrwxrwx  2 root root    4096 Jan 28 15:34 log`

Comment: File permissoins: `-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Jan 26 20:30 production.log`

Comment: Well to make sure this is not a permission problem you can check if the process running rails is owned by root: `ps -u root | grep rails` if is not is probably a permission problem if is the case then it could be something on the rails app itself

Comment: The command `ps -u root | grep rails` does not return anything!

Comment: Then I recommend you to run `ps aux | grep rails` to see which user owns the rails process and then change the permissions on the log file to that user and see if that works.

Comment: Its: `root     17848  0.0  0.0  11676  1004 pts/2    S+   18:30   0:00 grep --color=auto rails`

Comment: So it seems is not a permissions related problem, I think other things you can try is to check the value of `ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?` in the rails console or even remove that condition from your production.rb file to see if is correctly configuring the application

Comment: Ok I will try and its enabled. `root@sss:/var/www/sss-sss# cat .env
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: enabled`

Comment: I'm not sure the output from `ps aux` you've included above is the server process - that looks like the `grep` program processing the output from `ps`.  Is it possible the server process has a different name, e.g. `puma` ?  Is the Rails app server process definitely up and handling requests on the server?

Comment: @Leo No, that's not possible. I killed the nginx processes from `ps aux | grep "nginx"` and so everything is up and working as expected but only logs are not adding in the production file.

Comment: Ah ok, just to double check - was nginx running as root?  The only other thing I can think of is to check the logs in /var/log/nginx to see if it's writing anything in there.

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the input. All of those error files are empty in `/var/log/nginx`